# How to set up Grid 2 in selenium RC using through Java-TestNG

Tags: selenium-grid

I am new to Grid and am trying to set up Grid 2 in Selenium RC.

I have downloaded the selenium-server-standalone-2.1.0.jar. Also I have my TestNG test cases.

And I have a test XML like:

```
<suite thread-count="1" name="Suite" parallel="tests" verbose="10"><!-- tests -->
        <test name="FFTest" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="selenium.host" value="localhost"></parameter>
        <parameter name="selenium.port" value="5569"></parameter>
        <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*firefox"></parameter>
        <parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://www.google.com"></parameter>
        <classes>

            <class name="EmployeeHealth.TestScripts.EmployeeHealthRegressionSuite">
                <methods>
                    <include name="InitScript"></include> 
                    <include name="SelectAvoidableAdmissionModule"></include>
                    </methods>  
            </class>


        </classes>
    </test>
<test name="IETest" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="selenium.host" value="localhost"></parameter>
    <parameter name="selenium.port" value="5579"></parameter>
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="*iehta"></parameter>
    <parameter name="selenium.url" value="http://www.google.com"></parameter>
    <classes>

        <class name="EmployeeHealth.TestScripts.EmployeeHealthRegressionSuite">
            <methods>
                <include name="InitScript"></include> 
                <include name="SelectAvoidableAdmissionModule"></include>
                </methods>  
        </class>


    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

And I followed the below steps:

Start Hub:

```
        java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role hub
```

Start remote control supporting Firefox

```
        java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role RC -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS -port 5579
```

Start another RC supporting Internet explore

```
        java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role RC -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplore,platform=WINDOWS -port 5556.
```

And in my SetUp.java file, Am creating the selenium objects like:

```
        selenium =  new DefaultSelenium(host,Integer.parseInt(port),
                        browser, url);


                if ( browser.equalsIgnoreCase("*chrome")) {
                    RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
                    rcc.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(new File(
                            "test\\Resources\\ThirdParty\\FirefoxProfile\\"));
                    seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer(rcc);

                } else {
                    RemoteControlConfiguration rcc = new RemoteControlConfiguration();
                    rcc.setFirefoxProfileTemplate(new File("Object Repository\\SSL"));
                            //"src\\Script\\lib\\ThirdParty\\FirefoxProfile\\"));C:\\Biju\\NewFrameworkStrcuture\\Framework\\ABC_JSAF\\

                    seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer(rcc);
                    RemoteControlConfiguration a= seleniumServer.getConfiguration();
                    File uimap=new File("src\\Script\\lib\\user-extensions.js");
                    a.setUserExtensions(uimap);
                    //seleniumServer = new SeleniumServer();
                }
                //seleniumServer.start();
                selenium.start();
                selenium.windowMaximize();
                selenium.windowFocus();
```

By this way, when am running the xml file, the tests are running in sequence(First Firefox and then the IE). But not in parallel.

Also i tried giving the @Test parameter like

```
  @Test(dataProvider="CommonTestData",threadPoolSize = 3)
```

But i dont see any change in the seqence.

do any one got why this is happening?..

Appreciate for your help.

---

A J, Thanks for the reply.

I did changes in the XML suite and I made the dataprovider function as "parallel=true" and also added the Invokation function @Test parameter "InvoationCount=2",and configure the node  and am able to launch 1 IE and 1 FF parallel.

But now the problem is, in one browser(Say IE), my test cases are executing perfectly.But in the other browser(FF) ,after launching the browser, I don't see any other action performing on it.Not even opening my URL. in the console I got error : 
   "FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass Seleniumstart
        ("localhost", "5569", "*firefox", "http://www.google.com")
    com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be
     null; has this session been started yet?" 
Any idea on this?..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dataprovider, you also need to mention whether it should be called in parallel. Your CommonTestData method should have parallel=true option.

For executing using the XML, you need to increase the thread count to more than 1 for parallel execution.

Comment: while running in differet browsers, One browser able to run the tets case but the other browser throws error                 "FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeClass Seleniumstart ("localhost", "5569", "*firefox", "http://www.google.com") com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR Server Exception: sessionId should not be
 null; has this session been started yet?"

Comment: How are you passing the different browser values to your test?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Firefox XML config tries to send the test to a node on port `5569`. But in your actual client node connection string you are assigning it to use port `5579`. It also looks like your IE settings attempt to use `5579` but are started with `5556`.